# Gradle NoClassDefFoundError in jar dependency

Tags: gradle, dependency-management

I have developed a custom Gradle plugin and assembled as `jar`. This plugin has one dependency:

**plugin/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53'
}
```

I have included my plugin in another consumer project (as `jar` in `libs`):

**consumer/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'gg-release-plugin'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.myplugin.plugin:myplugin:1.0'
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but when code that uses classes of the dependency `com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53` is executed, I get an error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jcraft/jsch/JSch

What am I doing wrong? How can I include the dependencies in `jar` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, you've created a plugin jar library with compile time depnedency, that is not included anywhere in your final jar.

You can try to create your plugin jar as a fat jar, using [Gradle FatJar plugin](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) or something else. In that case, you'll have a single jar with all the dependent classes inside. But this could lead to problems, if someone will use the same library.

Or you can try to provide a JSch library together with your plugin jar and make a consumer build script dependency like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.myplugin.plugin:myplugin:1.0'
        classpath 'com.jcraft:jsch:0.1.53'
    }
}
```

As I know, if you use a Maven repo to publish your plugin, you can provide a pom.xml to describe all the plugin's dependencies, but as I see, you are using a flatDir for it, so, it seems not to be possible.

Comment: Thanks. I have provided the library in my consumer, and it works fine. I'd like to publish my plugin in a public repo, but I don't know how to describe the plugin's dependencies in pom.xml. Well, it will be in the future. Thanks.